# Carrousel tap event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [plugin](https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/) to create a 3D slider. It all works fine on a browser. When you click on an image, it becomes a active slide and comes to center. The same behavior (tap on image) is not working on iPad. How can i solve this problem on iPad ?

Plugin HTML Structure :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carrousel.css"/>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="banner">
    <section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
        <div class="dg-wrapper">
            <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
                <img src="images/1.jpg">
            </a>
            <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
                <img src="images/2.jpg">
            </a>
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
        <ol class="button" id="lightButton">
            <li index="0">
            <li index="1">
            <!-- ... -->
        </ol>
        <nav>
            <span class="dg-prev"></span>
            <span class="dg-next"></span>
        </nav>
    </section>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/carrousel.js"></script>
```

This is how you instantiate the plugin :

```
$('#dg-container').carrousel({
    current: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>jCarrousel Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/css/carrousel.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
      <div class="dg-wrapper">
        <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
          <img src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/images/1.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
          <img src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/images/2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
          <img src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/images/3.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
          <img src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/images/4.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" link="http://www.anotherhome.net">
          <img src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/images/5.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <ol class="button" id="lightButton">
        <li index="0">
          <li index="1">
            <li index="2">
              <li index="3">
                <li index="4">
      </ol>
      <nav>
        <span class="dg-prev"></span>
        <span class="dg-next"></span>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.anotherhome.net/file/jCarrousel/js/carrousel.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#dg-container').carrousel({
        current: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        interval: 3000
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the sample code from the website.
I added the full links so that you can copy and paste directly into your HTML document without needing to download anything. I would recommend you copy & paste this and then only change the images because the test website appeared to work when I tried it out on my tablet. 
Hope this helps!